# How can I use the variable here in another file? (React-Native)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

How can I use the 'const a' variable here in another file?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import colorsdata from '../../assets/data/colorsdata';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const a = colorsdata[0].word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export it. Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import colorsdata from '../../assets/data/colorsdata';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const a = colorsdata[0].word

export  { a };
```

Then import it. Like this:

```
import { a } from "./Path_or_FileName"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export a variable like so

```js
export const a = colorsdata[0].word
```

to make it available outside its file. Then you can use it in another file by importing it using your file's path:

```js
import { a } from "./path-to-file"
```